# Having trouble getting looping to get an accurate average WITHOUT using Math.Sqrt. Ideas?

Tags: c#, for-loop

So my professor wants us to make a program that takes in a number than spit out the square root for it. The catch is we aren't allowed to use Math.Sqrt or else there will be a 50% score penalty. So instead I'm using the following method from [here](http://pballew.net/oldsqrt.htm)...

1. Guess a number for the sqrt.
2. Divide the number by the guess.
3. Average the original guess and the new guess.
4. Make this average the current guess, and revert to step 2.

The thinking is once you do it 3-4 times (or more?) it should get closer, and closer to the actual sqrt.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void calculateSqr_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal wantedSqrt = Decimal.Parse(input.Text); //Takes the number from the textbox, and converts it to an int.
        Random rnd = new Random(); //We're going to pick a random number.
        decimal guess = rnd.Next(1, 100); //Pick a number between 1-100.

        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
        {
            decimal divHolder = wantedSqrt / guess; //Divide.
            decimal avgVal = (guess + divHolder) / 2; //Average.
            avgVal = guess; //Make the average our new guess.

            Console.WriteLine(guess); //Seems like all it does is write the number 10 times.
        }
        string wantedSqrtString = wantedSqrt.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(wantedSqrtString);
    }
}
```

As you can tell the issue is in my for loop. I thought that it would work so that it takes the wantedSqrt, dive it, average it with the guess, and then the new average would become the guess, and it would loop. Instead it just repeats the number 10 times in the output. What is going wrong here?

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You are wondering why guess does not change.  State all the places where it does change.

Comment: Where it does change? Well it is _supposed to_ change 12 times, but from what I see it is only changing twice (technically 12, but stays the same in the for loop).

Comment: Hint:  This line is wrong:  `avgVal = guess; //Make the average our new guess.`

Comment: You're not doing what I suggested.  State all the places -- line number, character offset -- where the local variable *guess* changes its value.

Comment: Oh whoops it was backwards. I should be telling guess to change not avgVal.

Comment: Correct. Read my article that I linked to.  You need to get a rubber duck and explain to the duck why the program is correct, one line at a time. When you got to the `avgVal = guess;` line, you should have been unable to explain to the duck why it is right, because it is wrong.

Comment: @EricLippert Not sure what you're getting at. It changes exactly on line 32, and 39. Besides I think I've already fixed my issue. It was just a dumb typo.

Comment: @EricLippert I did already. See my above comment. The issue was that I was telling the wrong value to change. Now that I've changed it to _guess = avgVal_ it is working properly.

Comment: What I'm getting at is: if your plan for the rest of your career is to ask stackoverflow every time you make a typo, you're going to have a short career. Learn how to read programs carefully and critically.

Comment: @EricLippert Fair enough. Never really thought about it that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code here:

```
    decimal wantedSqrt = Decimal.Parse(input.text); //Takes the number from the textbox, and converts it to an int.
    Random rnd = new Random(); //We're going to pick a random number.
    decimal guess = rnd.Next(1, 100); //Pick a number between 1-100.

    for (int i = 0; i <10; i++)
    {
    decimal divHolder = wantedSqrt / guess; //Divide.
     guess = (guess + divHolder) / 2; //Average.
     //Make the average our new guess.

    Console.WriteLine(guess); //Seems like all it does is write the number 10 times.
    }
    string wantedSqrtString = wantedSqrt.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(wantedSqrtString);
```